Rserve for R4.4.1?
I am trying to create a local Rserve connection to tableau desktop with plans to wrangle datasets in R and then push the clean/joined data frames to tableau or tableau cloud server for visualizations. There is some decent documentation how to make the connection using Rserve, however, those tutorials are 5-6 years old. Is Rserve still maintained for new versions of R? Is there another path forward to wrangling the data in R and pushing to tableau desktop or tableau cloud server?
> install.packages("RestRserve")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/025883/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RestRserve’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/PACKAGES'


The problem is the message "cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'" Is something blocking your internet connection to that website? Can you visit that URL in your browser? I can install the package just fine on my machine. The package was last updated on 2024-05-21.

I bet it is my work office wifi, which I know has had issues in the past for packages but recently they relaxed the firewall for python and r packages. It does seem the second warning is still pointing to my R version though? I will attempt to install through a hot spot.

The second warning only happens because it can’t pull the index of what’s available for your version of R. It’s likely just a firewall problem. Fix the errors in the order they appear.

"Is Rserve still maintained for new versions of R?" This question is easily answered (for any CRAN package) by using the search term "CRAN RestRserve" in your favorite internet search engine. This will find you this page: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RestRserve You can bookmark this link and just change its package part to check for other packages. If a package is not maintained anymore, you will find a link to the CRAN archive on this webpage. If you don't find anything, the package was never on CRAN (and you'll need to search Bioconductor or GitHub).

Thanks to the responses above, the Rserve package does work with new versions of R. It was an issue with my work firewall.
